# Layout и draw в context на HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Можно ли как то на Html5 в canvas задать уровни отрисовки? Например, сначала нарисовать 1 слой, потом 2, потом слой между 1 и 2, потом 0 слой.

Аналогия функции addChild("layout1",...) в as3? Есть такой в Html5?